Fixtures are not loaded and says they are not found, although they are there
In Django I have folder with fixtures\goods\categories.js and fixtures\goods\products.js. I installed PostgreSQL and I have tables categories and products. But when I write python manage.py loaddata fixtures/goods/categories.json I get the error: CommandError: No fixture named 'categories' found.
How do I load fixtures? This may be due to the fact that I may have previously loaded everything into something other than the environment. That is, I did python manage.py dumpdata not in the environment...

Do you have .js or .json?

As @AKX says in their comment, you you use .json files, not .js. JSON is a (very) strict subset of JavaScript that only allows to write data objects, no loops, variables, conditions, etc. .js would imply you have a JavaScript file.
This is also what the Django error says, it can not find categories.json, not categories.js.


rename categories.js to categories.json
run python manage.py loaddata fixtures/goods/categories.json


There was also a problem with the encoding. The encoding on the file was UTF-16, not UTF-8. It was converted using Notepad++

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
